# bash: command not found repository clone

Tags: windows, repository, git-bash

I've been trying to clone a repository on Windows 11 using the SSH key and I keep getting

```
$ ~ % cd Desktop
bash: /c/Users/danie: Is a directory


$ Desktop % git clone git@github.com:*****/prework-study--guide.git
bash: Desktop: command not found
```

So far I've tried reinstalling Git and still have the same issue, I've been reading that it's likely that the Git executable is not in the PATH environment variable. I downloaded GitHub desktop and the SSH key seems to work fine on the app. However, I am not sure how to fix this so I can have a remote GitHub repository clone.